# SQLite rawQuery error

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm prerry new to SQLite. I have a SQLite database with a user's details like this

```
public static final String USER_ID = "email";
public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
public static final String PASSWORD = "password";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "molo.db";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "user_profile";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//SQL to create new database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE +
        " (" +
        USER_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE , " +
        USER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

I can register new users and it works fine, I can see that it works when I pull the database from the emulator. 
I am now trying to log in with a user's details that is allready on stored on the database. I have searched and found a couple of solutions to this, however when I try to implement it I am receiving errors. I tried this:

```
public boolean verification(String Email) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ user_pofile +" WHERE "+ email + "=" + Email, null);
    if (c!=null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

to determine if the user's email allready exists within the database. Can anyone explain why `user_profile` and `email` are highlighted as error in the above rawQuery when they are the correct table and column names? Am I missing imports or something?
Cheers

Comment: Please add your full logcat

Answer (score 3):

`user_pofile` (typo there) and `email` are not in double quotes so they are treated as Java variable names and you don't have variables by such name in your code.

If you want to use variables, replace with `DATABASE_TABLE` and `USER_ID` or just put the `user_profile` and `email` in the double quotes.

Additionally, you need to quote string literals in your SQL in single quotes, or use variables.

For example,

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE email = ? ", new String[] { Email })
```

Moreover, `Cursor` won't be null and checking for `null` won't really work. To see whether the query matched anything, check that `moveToFirst()` returns `true`.

Comment: And the `cursor` will always be not `null`.

Comment: @CL. Thanks, that problem wasn't that apparent with the question's formatting earlier.

Comment: Ohke I not have this      Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user_pofile WHERE email =? ", new String [] {Email});
     if (c.moveToFirst())
     {
         return true;
     }
     return false;

Comment: But the rawQuery is now highlighted as an error. Any idea why? Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

The String `Email` that you're having at the end of the query is not surrounded by single quotes, syntax of a normal query is :

SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE userID = `'123'`,

so you have to surround Email variable with two single quotes : `"'"+Email+"'"`

Try this :

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ user_pofile +" WHERE "+ email + "=" + "'"+Email+"'", null);
```